# Python Multiprocessing (ForkAwareLocal, FileNotFoundError) - Main thread closed too early for many processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm experiencing some difficulties with multiprocessing in Python. Using the snippet below I'm getting two errors:

```
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

and

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've found that this is because the main process closes earlier than the sub-processes causing the subprocesses to be discarded, throwing these errors. I'm using `p.join()` as this should keep the main process waiting until the current process is done (if I understand correctly).

When using a small number of processes, the code works perfectly fine (`n_processes = 15`) but when `n_processes` becomes bigger than around 100 (differs per machine), the errors pop up.

I'm asking this question because it seems quite arbitrary when the main process closes too soon, and why the `p.join()` function is not doing what I'm expecting. I've read a ton of similar SO posts, plus documentation, but can't seem to figure it out. Could someone help me with this?

A minimal example is as follows:

```
"""Test for multiprocessing some large function."""

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time


def fun(d, i):
    """Simply add some data to the shared list."""
    time.sleep(2)
    d.append(("workerbee" + str(i), i))


def main(n_processes):
    """Let's do some arbitrary thing to test overall logic."""
    print("Starting!")
    with Manager() as manager:
        data = manager.list()  # <-- can be shared between processes.
        procs = []

        # Create n processes
        # if n is small => everything is fine
        # if n is large (>100) => ForkAwareLocal object has no attr connection
        for i in range(n_processes):
            procs.append(Process(target=fun, args=(data, i)))
            procs[-1].start()

        for p in procs:
            p.join()

        print(f'Result in main: {data}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Choose number of processes
    # n_processes = 15
    n_processes = 150

    start = timer()
    main(n_processes)
    end = timer()
    print(f'elapsed time: {end - start}')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, wat to just divide the total number of function calls that I wanted to do over the cpu_count(). This way, we still use all cores, but we don't need to open/close a process each time we call the function. So it's a workaround (that may be better than solving the issue), but I still don't understand why the MainProcess stopped ahead of time.